# Setting width of an element to that of one which overflows its container when both are in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Is there a CSS way of getting the blue line (class `.cover`) in this snippet to have a width equal that of the `.scrl_can`, which exceeds the width of its container `.prnt`?

The width of `.scrl_can` changes based on user input. A width of 100% sets the width of `.cover` to the width of `.prnt`. I tried `align-items: stretch;` in `.prnt` and it is the same as width of 100%.

I realize there are other ways of getting the blue line in that position and of the desired width, but the real UI piece has some relatively positioned elements that "drop" below the container when selected; and setting `overflow-x: hidden`, cuts them off; so I was trying this method which almost works.

Thank you.

```css
.flex_can {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 600px;
}
.space {
  flex: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
.prnt {
  flex: 1 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.scrl_can {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0.1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.cover {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_can">
  <div class="prnt">
   <div class="scrl_can">Some words here to span the width of prnt to make it a scroll can.</div>
   <div class="cover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: display:grid to .prnt ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you. I nver used grid before; the book I used made it sound as though it was replaced completely by flexbox. This worked not just in this made up example but in the real more-involved UI. Thanks for the help, again, because I recall your name helping me a few times in the past and just last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `::after` [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

```css
.flex_can {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 600px;
}
.space {
  flex: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
.prnt {
  flex: 1 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.scrl_can {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0.1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.scrl_can::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_can">
  <div class="prnt">
   <div class="scrl_can">Some words here to span the width of prnt to make it a scroll can.</div>
   <!-- <div class="cover"></div> DON'T NEED THIS ANYMORE -->
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I knew of this as an option and it appears to be a good one for my case since I think pseudo elements do not appear as child elements of the parent. It may be possible to accomplish the same with this, but `display:grid` works fine.